# Motion 5 - Link Parameters but Trail or Lag Value by a Few Seconds

Tags: animation, motion

How do I link the parameters of one element to another so that they mimic each other but have there be a 1-2sec delay in the mirroring behavior?  Normally I would use a link behavior to join the parameters but that doesn't allow you to set a delay as far as I am aware.